# List devices that can wake system from sleep with C++ & disable/enable them?

Tags: c++, winapi, sleep, power-management

I know that I can list devices that can wake Windows from a sleep mode using this command:

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
```

I can then disable a device from waking computer by doing this:

```
powercfg -devicedisablewake "device name"
```

I'm curious, is there a similar way to do it with C++ using an API or by changing some registry values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You proabaly should use [power management API functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373163.aspx).

Particularly, you can use `DevicePowerEnumDevices` function to list divices, that can wake up computer and `DevicePowerSetDeviceState` to enable/disable device from being sble to wake up computer.

Comment: Thanks. No support for XP though, right? I found a little bit of mentioning of registry settings that may apply to an older OS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837058

Comment: Here's also a C++ code sample on how to do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373243(v=vs.85).aspx